# ImageView not moving at all with animation- Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-sensors

I am trying to move a imageview(ball image) using sensorchange (on accelerometer) by using TranslateAnimation in my android application. But the application does not move the imageview. My logs look like the app is not even registering the accelerometer and I only see the ball imageview on the screen constant at a place. Can anybody please help me in resolving what am I doing wrong here? My code and logs are as follow:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

private ImageView ball=null;
public static int nwidth, nheight;
public static float xPosition, yPosition,oldx=0,oldy=0;
private float xAcceleration=0.0f,xVelocity = 0.0f;
private float yAcceleration=0.0f,yVelocity = 0.0f;
private float zAcceleration=0.0f;
public float frameTime = 0.999f;
private float mAlpha = 0.9f;
private static final String TAG = "Readings";
String toWrite=null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ball = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_ball);
    getScreenSize();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


private void getScreenSize()
{
    Point displaySize = new Point();
     getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(displaySize);

    Rect windowSize = new Rect();
    getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(windowSize);

   nwidth  = displaySize.x - Math.abs(windowSize.width());
   nheight  = displaySize.y - Math.abs(windowSize.height());
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent)
{
    {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

            yAcceleration = lowPass(sensorEvent.values[1], yAcceleration);
            xAcceleration = lowPass(sensorEvent.values[2],xAcceleration);
            zAcceleration = lowPass(sensorEvent.values[0],zAcceleration);

            toWrite = sensorEvent.values[0] + "," + sensorEvent.values[2] + "\n";
            writeCSV(toWrite);


            Log.i(TAG, "x:" + xAcceleration + " y:" + yAcceleration + "z:" + zAcceleration);
            updateBall();
        }

    }
}



// simple low-pass filter
float lowPass(float current, float filtered) {
    return mAlpha * current + (1.0f - mAlpha) * filtered;
}




private void writeCSV(String txtData)
{
    try {
        File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/"+ "Readings.txt");
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile,true);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =
                new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append(txtData);
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}


private void updateBall() {
   //for landscape orientation, treating z axis as x.

    xVelocity = (-zAcceleration * frameTime);
    float xS = (xVelocity)*frameTime;
    xPosition += xS;
    // yPosition += yS;
    yPosition++;
    setPosition();

    Log.i(TAG,"x:" + xAcceleration +" y:" + yAcceleration);
}

 private void setPosition()
 {
     TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(oldx, xPosition, oldy, yPosition);
     animation.setDuration(10);
     animation.setFillAfter(false);
     animation.setAnimationListener(new MyAnimationListener(ball));

     ball.startAnimation(animation);
     oldx=xPosition;
     oldy=yPosition;
 }


@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```

}

```
class MyAnimationListener implements Animation.AnimationListener {
  ImageView imageView=null;

   public MyAnimationListener(ImageView image)
   {
       imageView=image;
   }



@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    imageView.clearAnimation();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight());
  //  lp.setMargins(50, 100, 0, 0);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
}
```

}

```
08-12 01:03:21.348: I/art(3404): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-12 01:03:21.386: E/art(3404): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
08-12 01:03:21.386: I/art(3404): Debugger is no longer active
08-12 01:03:21.516: D/OpenGLRenderer(3404): Render dirty regions requested: true
08-12 01:03:21.522: D/Atlas(3404): Validating map...
08-12 01:03:21.568: I/OpenGLRenderer(3404): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-12 01:03:21.609: D/OpenGLRenderer(3404): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't even register the sensor,dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    SensorManager mSensorManager;
    Sensor mSensor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank T-Chen! I almost forgot that, but there was also a problem with my animation listeners. Its working now with accelerometer registered and animation listener corrected.